# How to get distinct sums when summing over repeated values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, window-functions

The issue I am having is with Postgres, in that using SUM with non-unique values or "sales" results in non-unique cumulative sums or "running sales".

Here is the query:

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(Sales) OVER (ORDER BY sales DESC) as running_sales 
FROM t;
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGqKS.jpg)

**Essentially I want this table to read:**

```
4--Motherboards------- 22----399
5--RAID Controllers----22----421
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Aside: If anyone is interested, this is what I was [following](http://dedyukh.in/index.php/abc-analysis-using-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the order in the `OVER` clause unique by adding `id` as second `ORDER BY` item:

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(Sales) OVER (ORDER BY sales DESC, id) as running_sales 
FROM   t
ORDER  BY sales DESC, id;
```

The way you had it, equal sales are treated as peers in the same `FRAME` and summed at once.
The [tutorial you were following](http://dedyukh.in/index.php/abc-analysis-using-sql) is no good for this particular query.

Also, you probably want to add an `ORDER BY` to the query itself to get stable results. This is very cheap, since it agrees with the sort order of the window function.

The way it is implemented right now, you normally get the results from this query in the order of the window function for simple queries, because that's the cheapest way. But Postgres makes no guarantee about the ordering of rows without `ORDER BY`, the arbitrary order can change without warning.

Comment: @user2449623: Consider the added info about `ORDER BY`.